# When I use XM_CALLCONV of DirectMath, Do I have to write that both declarations and definitions?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-12

```
// declaration in header file
void XM_CALLCONV F(FXMVECTOR vec);

// definition in source file
void XM_CALLCONV F(FXMVECTOR vec) { ... }
```

Do I have to writh XM_CALLCONV both of them? or just write it once at declareation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/vectorcall?view=msvc-160

I got it. In MScompiler, Just write it once at declareation is ok.

Comment: Be sure to read the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-internals#calling-conventions) page on the convention details.